# fetch data using multiple ids from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a mini e-commerce project, and I have an add to cart functionality,
so basically it works like this:

I sign up with an account, and whenever I add an item to cart, I use the account user id to store the ids of the items added to cart in the user data. Something like this:

```
/users
  /user-id-here
    ...some data
    ...a collection of ids which are the ids if the items i have bought

/products
  /product-id-1
  ...etc.
```

The issue is, is there a way I can fetch the products which i have bought using the ids i have stored? Or is there any better solution to this problem? Cuz like if i have 15000 items in the 'products' ref, and if i fetch all of them and check if my 'bought-list' ids include each individual item's id, that's a very bad thing... :/

Comment: Are you using firebase database or firestore?

Comment: I'm using firestore

Comment: Would the `.where()` function help in your situation?

Comment: What is the bad thing you're trying to avoid?  If you need to read 1500 documents, then that's what you'll have to do.  There are no shortcuts for this.

Comment: Like, I have 1500 products, and I have a few product ids saved from the last time i added some items to cart, and I am trying to fetch only the items that i have added to cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
let userProductsIds = ['id-1', 'id-2', '...'];
await db
    .collection(`products`)
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', userProductsIds);
    .get();
```

You can read more about firestore queries in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

EDIT:

This is what you should do instead.

```
const productsCollection = db.collection('products');
userProductsId.forEach(productId => {
   let product = await productsCollection.doc(`${productId}`).get();
   console.log(product);
})
```

So you will only fetch `n` times where `n` is the size of your user's item cart list

Comment: That won't work for 1500 documents.  `in` queries are limited to 10.

Comment: So your users will have 1500 or more items in their carts?

Comment: Like, I have 1500 products, and I have a few product ids saved from the last time i added some items to cart, and I am trying to fetch only the items that i have added to cart. how do you guys usually handle this kind of situation? like how would you implement it? :D